# Tensorflow Serving mobilenet_1.0_224_quant

Tags: tensorflow-serving

All,

I'm trying to serve a retrained model based on the mobilenet_1.0_224_quant architecture.

```
python -m retrain
    --architecture=mobilenet_1.0_224_quant
    --bottleneck_dir=/mypath/bottlenecks
    --how_many_training_steps=500
    --model_dir=/mypath/models
    --summaries_dir=/mypath/training_summaries/mobilenet_1.0_224_quant
    --output_graph=/mypath/graph.pb
    --output_labels=/mypath/labels.txt
    --image_dir=/mypath/images
    --saved_model_dir=/mypath/models/saved_models
```

tensorflow_model_server is able to load the servable version properly, but I haven't been able to consume it.

I'm using the same strategy that is used to consume inception_v3 based models.

```
for filename in filenames:
    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    files.append(f)
    data = f.read()
    imagedata.append(data)

request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
request.model_spec.name = 'default'
request.model_spec.signature_name = tf.saved_model.signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY

for data in imagedata:
    request.inputs['image'].CopyFrom(
        make_tensor_proto(data))
    result = stub.Predict(request, 10.0)  # 10 secs timeout
    print(result)
```

Nevertheless, I get the error:

```
grpc.framework.interfaces.face.face.AbortionError: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details="Expects arg[0] to be float but string is provided")
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The model expects the input to be floats but you are providing strings. You can use the `SavedModel` [command-line tool](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#install_the_savedmodel_cli) to inspect the input and output specifications of the model.